# How to configure nutch 1.4?

Tags: java, nutch

I am using this command to crawl some URLs:

```
./bin/nutch crawl urls/urls -dir crawl -depth 2
```

It is showing the following error:

```
Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the `$CLASSPATH`. i.e. the required `.class` file isn't there in the `CLASSPATH` that the `nutch` script sets up for itself. How did you install nutch? Did you follow [these instructions](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)? If not, try them, and share with us, which step it fails.

Answer (score 2):

See here http://www.params.me/2011/07/apache-nutch-13-setup.html

These steps worked for me. Let me know if you face any issues with this.

Comment: can we configure nutch 1.4 with hadoop 0.20